# Blur a CCLayerColor (for pause menu)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm curious if anyone knows of an already-implemented way to blur an entire CCLayer. I use a simple CCLayerColor set to black with a little opacity, but I would like to be able to blur the background enough to be indistinguishable blobs.

Comment: see http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6315

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CCLayerColor.

```
-(void)fadeBackground
{
    ccColor4B color = {0,0,0,255};
    CCLayerColor *fadeLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:color];
    [self addChild:fadeLayer z:7];
    fadeLayer.opacity = 0;

    id fade   = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1.0f opacity:160];//200 for light blur
    id calBlk = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        //show pause screen buttons here 
        //[self showPauseMenu];
    }];
    id sequen = [CCSequence actions:fade, calBlk, nil];

    [fadeLayer runAction:sequen];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a small tile that is translucent with some noise in it, and create a sprite that covers the screen where the texture parameters are set to repeat it?

```
CCSprite *blurSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blurtile.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
blurSprite.position = ccp(512,384);
ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
[blurSprite .texture setTexParameters:&params];
[self addChild:blurSprite];
```

I might have those params slightly wrong, but it should give the general idea.